# Error: list index out of range

Tags: python

I'm working with CSV files and here is what I have so far. I get an error that my index is out of range. It finishes the first for loop and then messes up. I am trying to populate a dictionary.

```
def read_table(file):
    line = file.readline()
    line = line.strip()
    keylist = line.split(',')
    d = {}
    for key in keylist:
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = []
    while line != '':
        line = file.readline()
        line = line.strip()
        val = line.split(',')
        for i in keylist:
            index = keylist.index(i)
            d[keylist[index]].append(val[index])
    return d
```

Comment: Do you use `NumPy`? If yes, `dat = np.genfromtxt('dat.txt', delimiter=',')`.

Comment: Opened files are iterable: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects. The Python tutorials are an excellent investment of your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` loop isn't going to break as soon as `line` becomes empty, it's just going to check that at the start of each loop.

So, when you've read all but the last line, you do this:

```
while line != '': # the last line wasn't empty
    line = file.readline() # but now this one is
    line = line.strip()
    val = line.split(',') # so this returns a single value
    for i in keylist:
        index = keylist.index(i) # so this raises an IndexError
        d[keylist[index]].append(val[index])
```

The *smallest* fix is to put the check directly after each `readline`:

```
while True:
    line = file.readline()
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        break
    val = line.split(',') # so this returns a single value
    for i in keylist:
        index = keylist.index(i) # so this raises an IndexError
        d[keylist[index]].append(val[index])
```

(Note that if there's a blank line in the middle of your file, you will return early instead of raising an error, because you're checking `line` after the `line = line.strip()`, so you can no longer distinguish between an empty line, `'\n'`, and end-of-file, `''`. If that's a problem, just move the test up one line.)

A *better* fix would be to just iterate over the file: `for line in file:` does exactly what you want the loop to do, without having to deal with `readline` and checking for empty strings and `break`ing from a loop and so on.

But a *much better* fix would be to  use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module and let it do what it does:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
reader = csv.DictReader(file)
for line in reader:
    for key, value in line.items():
        d[key].append(value)
return d
```

Or, alternatively, just build a list of dicts (which you can do with `list_o_dicts = list(reader)`), then convert it to a dict of lists at the end.